# How can you include path parameters in nested router w/ FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

How can I include one `APIRouter` inside another AND specify that some path param is a required prefix?

For context:
Let's say I have the concept of an organization and a user. A user only belongs to one organization. My web app could be structured as follows:

```
├── web_app
    ├── endpoints
        ├── __init__.py # produces main_router by including other routers inside each other
        ├── organization.py # contains endpoints relevant to the organization
        ├── user.py # contains endpoints relevant to the user
    └── main.py # includes main_router in app
```

Let's assume I want to achieve basic CRUD functionality for organizations and users. My endpoints could look something like this:

For orgs:

```
GET /api/latest/org/{org_id}
POST /api/latest/org/{org_id}
PUT /api/latest/org/{org_id}
DELETE /api/latest/org/{org_id}
```

For users:

```
GET /api/latest/org/{org_id}/users/{user_id}
POST /api/latest/org/{org_id}/users/{user_id}
PUT /api/latest/org/{org_id}/users/{user_id}
DELETE /api/latest/org/{org_id}/users/{user_id}
```

Since users are nested under orgs, within `user.py`, I *could* write all of my endpoints like this:

```py
user_router = APIRouter()
@user_router.get("/org/{org_id}/users/{user_id}")
async def get_user(org_id, user_id):
    ...
```

But that gets gross really quick. The `user_router` is completely disjointed from the `org_router` even though one should be nested inside the other. If I make a change to the org router, I now need to change every single user router endpoint. God forbid I have something nested under users....

So as per my question, I was hoping something like this would work:

```py
# user.py
user_router = APIRouter(prefix="/org/{org_id}/users")
@user_router.get("/{user_id}")
async def get_user(org_id, user_id):
```

```
# __init__.py
org_router.include_router(user_router)
main_router = APIRouter(prefix="/api/latest/")
main_router.include_router(org_router)
```

but that gives me the following error:
`AssertionError: Path params must be of one of the supported types`. I don't get the error if I remove `{org_id}` from the prefix, so I know `APIRouter(prefix="/org/{org_id}/users")` is the problem.

This is the only documentation we get from FastAPI on the matter: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#include-an-apirouter-in-another

Is what I'm looking for even possible? This seems like an extremely common situation so I'm curious what other folks do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting this error, but the thing that you are requesting (using path parameters in `APIRoute` prefix) is absolutely possible. When you include the `APIRoute` to the app instance, it will evaluate all routes and appends them from your dedicated `APIRoute` to the main `APIRoute`. The latter is always present in the `app = FastAPI()` app object. The path parameters itself are resolved upon a request.

Below is a fully working example, which will run as is:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"hello": "world"}


router = APIRouter(prefix="/org/{org_id}")


@router.get("/users/{user_id}")
def get_user(org_id: int, user_id: int):
    return {"org": org_id, "user:": user_id}


app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

We can check the outcome with curl:

```
% curl localhost:8000/org/1/users/2
{"org":1,"user:":2}%
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You're right this is totally doable. The `AssertionError` I was getting was because the path params _were_ actually doing their job. I had some endpoints that were not yet expecting the new param types.